# Перевести обозначение тысячи при отображении количества просмотров в вопросе

Tags: предложение, локализация

Сейчас тысяча обозначает буквой k (kilo) без перевода. Надо бы заменить на т (тысяча).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для меня такая замена абсолютно не интуитивна... `k` — это очень распространённое сокращение. Считаю, что менять не стоит.

Comment: В школе на уроках физики вы тоже стеснялись приставки «кило» у граммов, ньютонов и прочих джоулей? :)

Comment: @edem очень даже по делу. По какой ещё причине нужно менять «k» не на «к», а на «т»?

Comment: Для вопросов про локализацию сайта, используйте метку [meta-tag:локализация].

Comment: Кстати, в дубликате отметили более подходящий вариант «тыс.» — он хотя бы и в самом деле в русском языке используется. Правда, он длинее, и «к» мне всё равно больше нравится (я так-то не килофоб, хех)

Answer (score 4):

1. Мне бы больше понравилось число без округления.
2. `k` лучше чем `т`.